# How to scroll to last the item added in Kendo grid?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid that is always being updated by SignalR.

Currently my grid displays about 12 rows. Any rows added after that programmatically will not be visible as the scroll bar doesn't scroll down automatically

How do I programmatically scroll to the bottom of the grid, or is there a workaround to always make the last item added visible? Or scroll to last item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically to change the scroll position you will need to use the **dataBound** event of the Grid.
e.g.

```
dataBound:function(){
      this.content.scrollTop(this.tbody.height())
    },
```

Here is an live example with the web version of the Grid - same approach could be used with the wrappers:

http://jsbin.com/aqoqim/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a simple solution, but you can always use JavaScript to scroll to the element in question, using its `id='lastRowId'`.

```
// After adding your last row
window.location.hash = '#lastRowId';
```

or perhaps, scroll to the top of the grid (if this allows all rows to be visible),

```
window.location.hash = '#gridTop';
```

Comment: This uses the browser's scroll right? I need to scroll within the Kendo grid

Comment: What do you mean by scrolling *within* the grid then?